# Terraform or cloud formation for managing AWS server less Infrastructure

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

We are trying to create a infrastructure template that can be reused for Fargate deployments.Which tool would better fit this usecase, TerraForm or cloudformation?

Comment: If you are using AWS native only - use CloudFormation.

Comment: Even if you are using AWS only at this time, if you ever need to add something outside of AWS (for example MongoDB Atlas servers, or Cloudflare CDN) you'll be prepared for that if you used Terraform from the start.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinionated experience:

Terraform would give you a better language (HCL) and tooling (tf backends, workspaces, terragrunt, ...), and also work in other clouds and services if you need to deploy outside fargate.

CloudFormation would give you closer integration with AWS resources and services, as it is the foundation for a wide range of products. However, composing and deploying from YAML may get complex as the system grows, leading to other tools and workarounds.

You can get the "best of both" using the [Terraform Cloudformation Module](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudformation_stack) and so defining resources in CloudFormation but through the Terraform Tooling. Check the [gitops-blueprints](https://github.com/CaravanaCloud/gitops-blueprints/tree/main/infra/eks-ubuntu/eks_cluster) repo for a reference implementation.